# Is there a formula to automatically drag data form many columns into a new column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I would like to create a new table in Power Query (for Power BI) with 2 columns that contain data from other columns. These 2 new columns should have the data from the source columns stacked one over eachother. Attached is a link with the desired results.

https://ibb.co/dP1k6pd

What I need is a formula that will automatically update the new columns (ID and cars).

Have not tried anything as I do not have any ideas how to do this yet.

No code provided.

The new columns should automatically drag the data from the source columns and organize it vertically.

Best regards,
Denis

Comment: Use Pivot/unpivot to move from columns to rows and back agian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Go to the `Edit Queries` then select all 3 columns at the header (with shift and mouse click) then go to `Transform > Unpivot Columns > Unpivot Only Selected Columns`.

[image]

You can remove the middle column now and change the column headers to get your desired result.